# Targeting an outer parent's css with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

We are updating our customer questionnaire, which is set up so that they can return and update or edit their answers.  The basic html for each question (item) is below:

```
<div class="item">
  <span class="blue">The question ?</span>
  <div class="answer">
    Previous Answer <a href="" class="editlink">edit</a>
  </div> <!-- end div answer -->
  <div class="question">
    <textarea name="item-name" class="w90">Previous Answer or empty</textarea>
  </div> <!-- end div question -->
</div> <!-- end div item -->
```

When loading from the database, if there is a previous answer then the answer div will show and the question div will be hidden & populated with the previous answer.  If the customer clicks the edit link, then the answer div should hide and the question div show.

If there was no previous answer then the question div will show and the empty answer div will be hidden.

My thoughts are to create two item classes, .item-answered & .item-not-answered to reflect the two states that answer and question can be.  And then use those classes when the page is first built by PHP.

But I am trying to figure out how to use jQuery's automagical stuff to allow clicking on the editlink to change the css of the outer parent (labeled as "item" in my html above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after the parent jQuery method. (http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Try something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().addClass('item-not-answered');" class="editlink">edit</a>
```

Comment: That seems to work for the immediate parent which would be the surrounding div (answer), but I am trying to target the next higher parent, which is the outer div (item) so that I can effect both divs inside it.

Comment: OK, I tried $(this).parent().parent().addClass .... and that seemed to do the trick ... but is it the best way to do it??

Comment: You can use `parents().eq()` (with **s**, see [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)) selector to specify which ancestor element. Try `$(this).parents().eq(1).addClass('item-not-answered');` - the grandfather.

Comment: Thanks ... that eq() works like a charm could even mess with the great great great grandparents for fun.